# Can there be different degrees of brunt?

Tags: idioms

Is it grammatical to feel the greater or lesser brunt, or is it only grammatical to feel the brunt?
I searched but only found a handful of examples and mostly from non-native writers/speakers.

Comment: I'd say it would probably sound weird, which _is_ a good reason not to do it. The word is rarely used outside of the fixed phrases 'bear/bore//take/took the brunt of', and fixed phrases are often, as the name implies, resistant to modification. Also, 'brunt' means 'the major impact/force ... of', which is surely resistant to grading.

Comment: Can you give full sentences as examples (both alternatives)?